# ROSBridge connection with Android

Tags: javascript, android, websocket, ros

I'm using `webpack` in `nodejs` to create a **web server**, and I'm using [rosbridge](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite) to interface the web server with ROS.

Is there a way that I can connect the **web client** on an android tablet to `rosbridge` (I'm running the rosbridge node on the web server machine)?

I can see the UI on the client but I don't know how to interface it with ROS on Android.

Here is the [js package](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/my_threejs_gui_example) that I'm using, and I'm using [ROSLibJS](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/my_threejs_gui_example/blob/main/src/js/ROSInterface.js)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve. But if you have webserver running locally you could used DDNS service like noip.com (to get consistent domain) and port forward to expose your web server public ip and then just simply connect to via browser on android. All ROS stuff would run on computer ROS -> rosbridge -> roslibjs -> Website  ---internet---> Android browser

Comment: @Combinacijus I'm not using Internet, I'm using Local server created by `node.js`, I can open the site by connecting the Android device to the local wifi, but I can't communicate with ROS as the android device doesn't have a `rosbridge websocket` running.